# Unique constraint on sequelize column

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Using NodeJS and Sequelize 2.0, I'm writing a migration to create a new table. In addition to the primary key, I want to mark a second column to be enforced as unique. I can't find anything about this in the documentation.

```
migration.createTable('data', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    key: {
        // needs to be unique
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
    }
})
    .then(function () {
        done();
    });
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The following works:

```
key: {
    // needs to be unique
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
}
```

Comment: Ok. Now I feel like an idiot for not just trying that. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Yuri do you know where there are docs on Sequelize constraints?

Comment: I'm still able to insert duplicate rows into my SQLite database with this using `upsert`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @JamesKlein probably because you're not defining the unique on the .sync()

Comment: Following up two years later - how would you find this out from the docs, or without asking on SO?

Comment: @DonnyP not 100% sure but at the time, I may have just quickly looked it up in the source code.

Comment: @DonP The documentation for Sequelize is pretty bad. As far as I can tell, there's no reference that shows every column option. The return values of most methods are documented only as "Promise." I'm going to cut a lot of slack for anyone whose needs are not addressed by that mess.

Comment: `unique` is not listed in sequelizejs' doc for attribute validation. Don't understand why such a commonly used feature is not even mentioned in the doc.

Comment: New to the party but I am feeling your pain ... the docs I've read stop at `attributes: Object`.

Comment: check this: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-init

Comment: as of now it's mentioned here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html

Comment: Maybe those docs require a PR @user938363 ?